# Power Bi to PostgreSQL connection

Tags: database, postgresql, powerbi-desktop, pgadmin-4

I Want to connect power bi to postgresql, it is showing me following error: An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
Please guide how to connect to postgresql, do we need any connector? if so then how to install it?

I have downloaded ngpsql but dont know how to install it

Comment: Have a look at: [PowerQuery PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/postgresql)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.